# Conditional Fields Module in drupal 8

Tags: 8

Hi I have enabled the drupal 8 conditional fields module , but I do not see anywhere to configure it, the "Malnage Dependencies" tab that is supposed to appear does not show.  Am I missing a step?
thanks,

Comment: I am closing this question as the answer is that the OP didn't look at the full content of a page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the code, [these are the admin routes](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/conditional_fields/tree/conditional_fields.routing.yml). The [links file](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/conditional_fields/tree/conditional_fields.links.menu.yml) would indicate that Conditional Fields should appear in the Structure area of the admin. Did you clear cache after enabling it? It should be in the Structure menu.

Comment: i cleared the cache, then go to admin/structure, there is not option for Conditional fields

Comment: Hitting `/admin/structure/conditional_fields` directly does nothing? Sounds like a bug in this module or perhaps your version of Drupal.

Comment: okay I guess i have to ask in the module page

Comment: sorry I didnt see it because it was at the bottom of the structure page , I assumed it would be alphabetical!